# deducting a type T for std::function from a lambda function

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how the following code works :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> struct Identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> void foo(T val, typename Identity<function<void(T)>>::type f)
{
    f(val);
}

int main ()
{
    foo(1337,[](int x){ cout << "lambda " << x << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

There is no choice of `T` that will make the lambda type equal to `std::function(void(T))`type, so that's why the metafunction is needed.

I know that the nested-name-specifier `::` is a brick wall so that will make the compiler not to try to deduce a type `T` for that parameter.

So I tried the same code but without the `T val` function parameters and `T` could not be deduced.

Does that mean that the compiler does the following steps when you call

`foo(1337,[](int x){ cout << "lambda " << x << endl; });`

1. arg is 1337 and param is `T val` // T is deducted to be an int
2. brick wall, won't try to deduce the type from the second argument

Will the compiler now call `Identity<function<void(int)>>` using the type `T` that was deducted from step 1 or will it do something else?

Comment: Pretty much. You deduce each parameter from the deduced contexts that they are used in, then substitute the deduced arguments (along with any explicitly specified and default arguments), then go to overload resolution.

Comment: Even creating an explicit `function<void(int)>` object to pass as parameter, the compiler was unable to deduce T from it.

Comment: you can call it with an explicit function, the compiler will do an implicit conversion.

   `template <typename T> void foo(T val, function<void(T)> f)
   {
        f(val);
   }

    int main ()
    {
        function<void(int)> f = [](int x){ cout << "lambda " << x << endl; };
        foo(1337, f);
       return 0;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you're right.

Unfortunately, the language for template argument deduction in the standard is so incredibly verbose, I daren't even begin trying to prove this as a fact.

Comment: The compiler will compare every template parameter with every argument and deduce a type for T. Only if the same type T is deduced for each param the template will compile, otherwise it will fail. Also template type deduction won't consider any implicit conversions, it will just fail to compile.

Comment: @Ody: Deduction cannot occur for the second parameter.